# Regarding using macro function in UI test target

Tags: unit-testing, compiler-errors, macros

I’m writing UI unit test.

I know that target source codes are not included in UI unit test bundle as default. But I’d like to use some source codes in UI unit test target. However macro functions like `_DDLogInfo` and `_DDLogError` are causing compile error with the message

> Implicit declaration of function ‘DDLogInfo’ is invalid in C99.

I added those sources in UI test target.

1. Question 1: Is macro functions is not available in UI Unit test
   target?
2. Question 2: Does anyone knows hot to avoid compile error with
   macros?

First try:

- remove cocoklumberjack pod in UI test target
- added `void DDLogInfo(NSString *format, ...)`" as c function and it is included in UI test target.

[image: [enter image description here]

Comment: Please state the compiler and programming language you use in your question or title.

Comment: I'm using xCode 9.1, developing iOS appv & primary language is objective-c. thanks.

Comment: Okay. So _I_ will put that into your question ...